# Why is checkmark disappearing when using pdf2image

Tags: python, pdf2image

I am using `pdf2image.convert_from_path` in python

to convert a pdf to images.

There is a checkbox with a tick inside it in the pdf. However the tick disappears when I am using the utility.

Anybody knows how I can resolve this ?

Comment: can you show the code and output that you are getting for clear understanding?

Comment: as this question is quite specific to a particular PDF, you probably need to make it available to get an answer.  If it's a private document, then you might have to figure out how to replicate the problem with another document.